# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am fire this sql query and then return this error.

**My Error:**

> 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:
>   '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,122,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,157,153,154,155,156'
>   The SQL being executed was:

**My Query:**

```
DELETE FROM groups_module_actions 
WHERE module_action_id NOT IN('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,122,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
21,22,23,24,25,26,157,153,154,155,156') AND group_id='1'
```

Comment: is that a list of number or a string? Which is it meant to be?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Skip the quotes in the `NOT IN ()`, its expecting datatype `integer` not a `string`.

```
DELETE FROM groups_module_actions WHERE module_action_id 
NOT IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,122,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
21,22,23,24,25,26,157,153,154,155,156) 
AND group_id=1
```

Comment: For reasons around implicit conversion, quoted numbers result in the comparison being compared as a double. So don't quote numbers that are no being compared against strings (e.g. phone numbers).